# Как подключить библиотеку (.а) к проекту MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, openstreetmap, компоновщик

Здравствуйте
Нужно собрать проект под MS Visual Studio.
Проект зависит от библиотеки libosmpbf.a, которая поставляется исключительно в виде статической библиотеки в формате gcc. Можно ли библиотеку libosmpbf.a преобразовать в libosmpbf.lib. При помощи MinGW? Прошу варианты с Cygwin не рассматривать.

Comment: Пересобрать библиотеку под MSVC плохой вариант? Вы уверены что собранная она не тянет за собой ничего из Linux?

Comment: Библиотеку не могу пересобрать под MSVC. Так как кроме хедеров и статической либы libosmpbf.a ничего нет в репозитории https://github.com/scrosby/OSM-binary

Comment: Она использует libprotobuf от google, эту библиотеку я уже подключил без проблем и zlib тоже есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто так использовать библиотеку, собранную для GCC не получится. Библиотека, собранная под другую систему, может использовать специфичные для той системы функции. Даже в случае одной и той же ОС могут возникнуть проблемы в связи с тем, что GCC и MSVC используют разные runtime-библиотеки, которые могут быть несовместимы между собой.

Правильный путь в данном случае - собрать библиотеку из исходников с импользованием нужного компилятора.

В конкретно вашем случае исходники поставляются с библиотекой. Во время сборки C++ файлы генерируются из .proto файлов с использованием protobuf compiler. Вам нужно для сборки

1. Установить cmake
2. Установить protobuf compiler
3. Открыть консоль Visual Studio.
4. Перейти в папку библиотеки.
5. Убедиться, что путь к исполняемым файлам cmake и proto compiler находятся в пути поиска (`PATH`)
6. Выполнить

   ```
   cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"
   nmake
   ```
7. PROFIT

Comment: 100% ответ
Огромное спасибо!
Без вашего ответа я бы не справился.